# Add 72 seconds to Now.ToString and show result?

Tags: vb.net

When I run following code MsgBox shows 2015.12.15-03.31.21

```
MsgBox(Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss"))
```

I want to add 72 seconds to 2015.12.15-03.31.21 and hope to see 2015.12.15-03.32.33.

I tried following code but it doesnt work.

```
MsgBox(Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss") + 72)
```

Any support?

Comment: Not a .net person, but isn't there a DateTime.AddSeconds method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the 'AddSeconds' method as follows:

```
DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(72)
```

In your example, it would be:

```
MsgBox(Now.AddSeconds(72).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.